# Most clear and pythonic way to keep track when a new string occurs when going through strings of a string generator

Tags: python

Here is a piece of code that goes through strings generated by a string generator, and when it encounters a new string, it saves all the previous same strings into one item in a new list

```
import random

stringList = [ 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
tracker = []
combo = []
for i in range(20):
    item = random.choice(stringList)
    if len(tracker)==0:
        tracker.append(item)
    elif item in tracker:
        tracker.append(item)
    else:
        combo.append( ' '.join(tracker) )
        tracker = []
        tracker.append(item)

for item in combo:
    print(item)
```

Result

```
e
a a
d
e e
c
a
e e e e e e e e e e
d
```

I am wonder if there is a clearer, more compact,  more pythonic, and possibly more computationally efficient way to get the same result.

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, also is not clear, at least to me, what the code is doing or is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
# This input data is adapted from your output, since your input is
# randomly generated and I want to show the same result.
items = 'eaadeecaeeeeeeeeeed'

from itertools import groupby

for k, g in groupby(items):
    print(' '.join(g))
```

Output:

```
e
a a
d
e e
c
a
e e e e e e e e e e
d
```

P.s. The method for generating `items` doesn't seem to be relevant to the question, so I left it off. You could just as easily replace the string with any [iteratable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Comment: That's different input, and no random selection.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's on purpose. I just edited to clarify why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` over the output of `random.choices` instead:

```
import random
from itertools import groupby
for _, g in groupby(random.choices(stringList, k=20)):
    print(*g)
```

Sample output:

```
a a
e
a
c
e e e
c c
e e
a
c c
d
e e e e
```